# Better way to complete Click event?

Tags: vb.net

So I have a tool that pings equipment, all fully coded and working. But, I want to make a change, and want to see if there is a easy/smart/better way to do it.

Current code:

```
 Private Sub BKUPingIcon_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BKUPingIcon.Click
    Shell("ping " & BKUBox.Text & " -t", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(BKUBox.Text) Then
            'Online
            If GetPingMs(BKUBox.Text) < 125 Then
                'Good ping
                BKUPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
            Else
                'Bad ping
                BKUPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingHIGH
            End If
        Else
            BKUPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
            'Offline
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now, I want to add a RightClick option, and only way I know, is to do a complete overhall on the code, and that is basicly recoding everything. This is how I have it working, but would like to alter to make it easier to alter everything.

```
Private Sub PRIPingIcon_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PRIPingIcon.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        Try
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(PRIBox.Text) Then
                'Online
                If GetPingMs(PRIBox.Text) < 125 Then
                    'Good ping
                    PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
                Else
                    'Bad ping
                    PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingHIGH
                End If
            Else
                PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
                'Offline
            End If

        Catch
        End Try
    Else
        Shell("ping " & PRIBox.Text & " -t", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
        Try
            If My.Computer.Network.Ping(PRIBox.Text) Then
                'Online
                If GetPingMs(PRIBox.Text) < 125 Then
                    'Good ping
                    PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
                Else
                    'Bad ping
                    PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingHIGH
                End If
            Else
                PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
                'Offline
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Any better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code is the same except for the Shell() call, so:

```
Private Sub PRIPingIcon_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PRIPingIcon.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Shell("ping " & PRIBox.Text & " -t", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
    End If
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(PRIBox.Text) Then
            'Online
            If GetPingMs(PRIBox.Text) < 125 Then
                'Good ping
                PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingUP
            Else
                'Bad ping
                PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingHIGH
            End If
        Else
            PRIPingIcon.Image = My.Resources.PingDOWN
            'Offline
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks simple enough, I did see I cannot use the event 'Click' for the e.button. Is that correct? That being the case makes it a pain also

Comment: Right...because it isn't standard practice to provide different behavior with a **direct** right click.  Normally you'd have a Context Menu appear on a right Click to show that something different can be achieved.